# How to use multiple consumers in different programming language for same group ID in Kafka

Tags: c#, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I wanted to create a load balancing in Kafka (multiple programming languages) for a topic. So I did the following.

1. Created a topic with 4 partitions.
2. Created a producer in C# (producing messages every second)
3. Created one consumer(consumer1) in C# (consumer group: testConsumerGrp)
4. Created one more consumer(consumer2) in NodeJs (consumer group: testConsumerGrp)

I used [confluent.kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) in C# and [kafkajs](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs) in NodeJs.

I Open the producer and keep it running.

1. If I run only C# consumer, it works fine.
2. If I run only NodeJs consumer, it works fine.
3. If I run multiple C# consumer (only c# and less than 4 instances), it works fine.
4. If I run multiple NodeJs consumer (only NodeJs and less than 4 instances), it works fine.
5. If I run one C# and one NodeJs consumer then I am getting `Inconsistent group protocol` error

Can't we use two programming languages for a same consumer group?

**Producer in C# - windows form**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Confluent.Kafka;

namespace KafkaProducer
{
    public partial class frmProducer : Form
    {
        const string TOPIC = "testTopic";
        private IProducer<Null, string> pBuilder;

        public frmProducer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // instead of sending some value, we send current DateTime as value
                var dr = await pBuilder.ProduceAsync(TOPIC, new Message<Null, string> { Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() });

                // once done, add the value into list box
                listBox1.Items.Add($"{dr.Value} - Sent to Partition: {dr.Partition.Value}");
                listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            }
            catch (ProduceException<Null, string> err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Failed to deliver msg: {err.Error.Reason}");
            }
        }

        private void frmProducer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092" };
            pBuilder = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build();

            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void frmProducer_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            pBuilder.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer in C# - windows form**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Confluent.Kafka;

namespace KafkaConsumer
{
    public partial class frmConsumer : Form
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public frmConsumer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StartListen()
        {
            var conf = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = "test-consumer-group",
                BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
            };

            using (var c = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(conf).Build())
            {
                c.Subscribe("testTopic");

                //TopicPartitionTimestamp tpts = new TopicPartitionTimestamp("testTopic", new Partition(), Timestamp.  )
                //c.OffsetsForTimes()

                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var cr = c.Consume(cts.Token);

                            // Adding the consumed values into the UI
                            listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                listBox1.Items.Add($"{cr.Value} - from Partition: {cr.Partition.Value}" );
                                listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
                            }));
                        }
                        catch (ConsumeException err)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show($"Error occured: {err.Error.Reason}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    // Ensure the consumer leaves the group cleanly and final offsets are committed.
                    c.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }

        private async void frmConsumer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => StartListen());
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer in NodeJs**

```
const { Kafka } = require("kafkajs");

const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ["localhost:9092"]
});

const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: "test-consumer-group" });

const run = async () => {
  // Consuming
  await consumer.connect();
  await consumer.subscribe({ topic: "testTopic", fromBeginning: false });

  await consumer.run({
    eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
      console.log(message.value.toString() + " - from Partition " + partition);
    }
  });
};

run().catch(console.error);
```

If I run C# and NodeJs consumer at same time then getting `Inconsistent group protocol` error.

**How to use multiple consumer from different programming languages in Kafka?**

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**:

This may not have as much to do with the different languages as you might think. This is happening due to the differences in the protocols of the 2 consumer clients (and their libraries).

Try setting the following property in both the consumer clients:

`partition.assignment.strategy = round-robin`

*Note: I've just supplied the general property so you'll need to look at the language specific versions for your clients. You could even set this to `range` but keep it consistent.*

**The explanation goes like this**:

Reading through the protocol on [Kafka's wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol) to find out the root cause of `Inconsistent group protocol` - it turns out that this is returned when:

1. There is an active consumer group with active/running consumers
2. And a new consumer arrives to join this group with a protocol type (or a set of protocols) that is not compatible with that of the current group

Now, there could be various aspects in the `ConsumerGroupProtocolMetadata` but one of the aspects that does seem to differ in the libraries of the clients that you're using is the `partition.assignment.strategy`.

The [dotnet client](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) is a wrapper around [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) defaults the value of the above property to `range`. Here's the [reference](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/1622#issuecomment-355528237).

where as

[kafkajs](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs) as per the [documentation](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#custom-partition-assigner) defaults it to `round-robin` - hence causing the inconsistency.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still I am getting the same error. I changed the PartitionAssignmentStrategy in C# as RoundRobin and did the same for NodeJs also, but not helping :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes one year too late but this happens because of the same group naming

When you start the C# client it creates a group for its consumers.

E.g. group-1 (group-1-consumer-1,group-1-consumer-2, etc) - These names are automatically allocated so don't bother. I think you can set these manually but is not recommended to avoid potential name collision.

Now, when you set this in motion you cannot add the same group from a different group runner (from another microservice).
See what Lalit quoted from Kafka wiki:

> There is an active consumer group with active/running consumers

Now, when you will start the nodeJs one, you should use a different group name as most likely will carry out other tasks with that data.

Yes, you can subscribe both groups to the same topics as Kafka will keep an offset for each group and where they left of.